# How to change a boolean instance of a class in another view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, observedobject

I want to tap a button in one view and change the text on another view.
The button that changes the bool is on LessonOne and the text I want to show in on my ContentView.

The code in my Lesson One is:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class LessonTwoButton: ObservableObject {
    let didChange = PassthroughSubject <Void, Never >()
    var ButtonIsTapped = false {didSet {didChange.send()}}
}

struct LessonOne: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var ActivateNextLesson = LessonTwoButton ()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            Button (action: {
                self.ActivateNextLesson.ButtonIsTapped.toggle()
            }
            , label: {
                Text("Activate the next lesson")
            })
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

The code in my ContentView is:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var lessontwobutton = LessonTwoButton()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            
            VStack{
                Text("Hello, world!")
                    .padding()
                
                if lessontwobutton.ButtonIsTapped{
                    Text ("The button has been pressed. Your lesson is unlocked")}
                else{
                    Text("This lesson is locked")
                }
                
                NavigationLink (
                    destination: LessonOne(),
                    label: {
                        Text("Next view")
                    })
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

The code runs, but it just doesn’t bind… I go on LessonOne, tap the button, get back to ContentView and nothing is changed. Can you please tell me what to do?

Comment: Off-topic, but you are not following the [Swift naming guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#follow-case-conventions) - variables/properties should be in `lowerCamelCase`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the same `LessonTwoButton` instance in both views:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var lessontwobutton = LessonTwoButton() // create in parent only
    ...
```

```
struct LessonOne: View {
    @ObservedObject var ActivateNextLesson: LessonTwoButton // declare only
    ...
}
```

```
NavigationLink(
    destination: LessonOne(ActivateNextLesson: lessontwobutton), // pass here
    label: {
        Text("Next view")
    }
)
```

And `LessonTwoButton` can be simplified:

```
class LessonTwoButton: ObservableObject {
    @Published var ButtonIsTapped = false
}
```

Comment: Ok I used the same instace in both views, but it still doesn't change.

ContentView:
`
  @ObservedObject var ActivateNextLesson: LessonTwoButton
`
and
`
NavigationLink (
                    destination: LessonOne(ActivateNextLesson: LessonTwoButton()),
                    label: {
                        Text("Next view")
                    })
`
LessonOne:
`
class LessonTwoButton: ObservableObject {
    @Published var ButtonIsTapped = false
}
`
and
`
@ObservedObject var ActivateNextLesson : LessonTwoButton
`

Comment: @ŞtefanDanSima You can't do `NavigationLink ( destination: LessonOne(ActivateNextLesson: LessonTwoButton())` - this way you're creating a new instance in the destination. Note that I'm creating this instance in the `ContentView`.

Comment: So how do I do this? If I want to tap a button, send me on another view and tap a button in the second view that would display me something on the first view?

Comment: @ŞtefanDanSima I updated my answer so it's more clear.

Comment: It works. Thank you so much! I've been struggling with this for 3 weeks. You're the best!